# Get value of date and store it in MySQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql

I've got the error:

> INPUT STRING WAS NOT IN A CORRECT FORMAT

when running the code below.

So what do you think here is the error? How will I format the date in the DateTimePicker to store properly in MySQL database?

Here is my code (I included only the relevant code which I think is the error):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rdate", _order.dateTimePicker_Requested.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ndate", _order.dateTimePicker_Needed.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodeDate", Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now` _is_ a `DateTime`.

Comment: @SLaks Yes Sir the type is DateTime in the 3rd Parameter while in the 1st and 2nd it is only a Date.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your MySQL columns are strings (which they shouldn't be), you should be passing actual dates as parameters.

Don't call `.ToString()`.

Comment: To elaborate on that, you're passing dates as strings in a particular format. Imagine what would happen if your database would move to another server with a different format. Just pass them as `DateTime` objects and let the MySQL database do the rest. It can save you a lot of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You should set :

```
string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", your_date);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your variable represents datetime value then its no need to convert it to string it automatically mapped with MySQL column type and if it still not work then reply.
I will post with some code that will convert datetime to proper so that it would mapped with column.

Thank you.